# Clear the sequencer memory cache?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, tracking, memory-management, cache

I'm doing some motion tracking, and to quickly edit things I preload the frames into the memory. However, this fills up my ram, and sometimes (e.g when I'm not working with the footage) I want to clear it out of memory. Can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you reload the clip on the Movie Clip Editor, the cache will be cleared.

[image]

Also keep in mind that the amount of memory used for the cache can be managed on the System Preferences (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>) ->System ->Sequencer/Clip Editor ->Memory Cache Limit

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It should be done automatically. Old stuff won't be hold as you can see when you lower your used RAM amount in the System settings to a few MB. Only the last few frames would be hold in your RAM. Watch it in the Movie Clip Editor as you play your footage.

Comment: I'm asking how to clear it. I know it will automatically get rid of it if it needs to use it for something else, but I'm talking about how to do it manually

Comment: How should I know what you already know? But it might help out to know it's not necessary to clear it manually. If it won't help you out might help out others. This site is about knowledge transfer ;-)